# Is adding product to quote through enhanced experience customizable?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales

When products are added through enhanced experience batch is executed on webapi by sending multiple create record requests. And this is payload of one request:

```
POST /api/data/v9.0/quotedetails HTTP/1.1
    
{
    "ispriceoverridden": false,
    "ofml_lineno": 1,
    "ofml_section": 1,
    "priceperunit": 2105.26,
    "productdescription": "Testing - prod description",
    "productid@odata.bind": "/products(848ecbf6-5878-ec11-8d21-000d3ad55516)",
    "quantity": 1,
    "quoteid@odata.bind": "/quotes(d07f272c-70b3-ed11-b596-6045bdd2b5e7)",
    "uomid@odata.bind": "/uoms(baae8a55-cb0b-ec11-b6e6-002248422a3d)"
    }
```

Problem is that this request fails in 2 cases:

1. Error: *You cannot set both 'productid' and 'productdescription' for the same  record.* This happens when product description is set on Product and length is less than 500 chars.
2. If we have product description set and longer than 500 chars this error occurs: *The length of the 'productdescription' attribute of the 'opportunityproduct' entity exceeded the maximum allowed length of '500'.*

It works only if product description is empty.
My question is if this is customizable so that I can remove *productdescription* property in transferring from Product to QuoteProduct i.e. ?

This applies on adding product to quote, opportunity, invoice, it's same in all cases. And also to add that I'm using Dynamics 365 Sales, Enterprise Edition (9.0.22121.10002)

Comment: I read the same issue in another forum, this is a bug of the new experience if I am correct, you can disable the new experience meanwhile

Comment: Thanks @GuidoPreite! I'm pretty sure it's bug, but just posted question for that 2% of chance for some workaround :) Thing is that productdescription on quoteproduct is single line of text, and description on product is multi lines.